# Is there a way to decrease time for loop in python?

Tags: python, loops

I have a `for each` loop going through a list of roughly 10000 elements. Each Element is a tuple of varying but roughly the same length. I'm measuring the time it takes for each loop to compute and the time is starting of very small, about 1/10th of a second but increases the longer the loop runs. Towards the end it takes over 4 seconds to compute it.

Is there anything I can do to keep the time roughly the same? Or at least decrease the time it takes towards the later stages of the loop?

I already changed the inner loop from `range(0, len(tuple))` to `enumerate(tuple)` but it didn't change the time it takes.

```
for patient in patient_list:
    starttime = time.time()
    count = count + 1
    string = patient[0]
    for i, item in enumerate(patient):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            string = string + ","  + str(patient[i])
    string = string + "\n"
    outputfile.write(string)
    endtime = time.time()
    print("Patient " + str(count) +  " of " + str(total_patients) + " in " + str(endtime-starttime))
```

Comment: Is patient_list a generator?

Comment: This is likely related to writing the file. Can you show how you create the `outputfile` instance? Have you tried timing how long the write takes? Have you considered collecting all strings in a list and then writing them all in one go?

Comment: its a list i create earlier in the script

Comment: i use "with open("baseline.csv", "w") as outputfile:" to create the instance. i will try timing the write and come back

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the lag on Linux. If you could provide a mock dataset on pastebin or something that'd be cool.

Comment: the (now deleted) answer pointed me in the right direction. I changed the datastructure behind the patient_list to a list of dicts and did the output with csv.write() now its done in no time.